# error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'LinkedList<int>::Node *' to 'LinkedListIterator<const T>'

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I am trying to implement linked list iterator and getting compile error. In my test code T is int. When I try to call iterator constructor, it doesn't see the option where Node is passed as an argument.

Here is the code:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedListIterator
{
    typedef typename LinkedList<T>::Node Node;
    ...

    LinkedListIterator(Node* p) : p(p) {}
    LinkedListIterator(const LinkedListIterator& other) : p(other.p) {}
    LinkedListIterator& operator=(LinkedListIterator other) { std::swap(p, other.p); return *this; }
    ...
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    struct Node ...

    friend class LinkedListIterator<T>;
    friend class LinkedListIterator<const T>;

    ...

    typedef LinkedListIterator<T> iterator;
    typedef LinkedListIterator<const T> const_iterator;

    ...

    const_iterator begin() const //where error happens
    {
        return const_iterator(head->next);
    }
...

};
```

Comment: What is `head->next`?!

Comment: @KerrekSB It's `LinkedList<int>::Node *`. It's not in the code, but it is in the error message as the conversion source type.

Comment: Why don't you include the definition of `next` above? It's always helpful to have **all** of the relevant code available, so we aren't left guessing.

Comment: sorry I've kept getting "too much code" error and couldn't post until I trimmed everything... Node is basically a struct with next pointer and T data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're attempting to construct `LinkedList<int>::const_iterator`, which is `LinkedListIterator<const int>`. `LinkedListIterator<const int>` has two constructors allowing conversions: one copy constructor that I'll ignore, and one from `LinkedListIterator<const int>::Node *`. `LinkedListIterator<const int>::Node *` is `LinkedList<const int>::Node *`. But you don't have a `LinkedList<const int>::Node *`, you have a `LinkedList<int>::Node *`. That's a completely different type, so the compiler is right to reject the conversion.

If you want to add any sort of inheritance relation between `LinkedList<int>` and `LinkedList<const int>` (I don't know if it makes sense), you could add a partial specialisation and let `LinkedList<const T>::Node` relate to `LinkedList<T>::Node`, but without any special work on your part, a compiler error is all you're going to get.

Comment: oh gosh you are right, C++ is making my brain want to explode! :)